# Windows screenshot with scaling

Tags: c#, .net, windows, gdi

I am trying to take screenshots of every screen on my windows 10 machine.
My system has 2 monitors which are of multiple DPIs.

- My primary monitor has "scale and layout" set to 200%.
- My secondary
  has "scale and layout" set to 100%.
  [image]

I am trying to use C# to take a screenshot of every single monitor.
However my scaled monitor is reporting the wrong coordinates:
Everything is halved.
As a result, the primary monitor's screenshot is only 1/4th  of the screen area (width/2,height/2).

Here is my code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace CsSourceClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Screen[] screens;
            screens = Screen.AllScreens;


            int i = 0;

            foreach (var screen in System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens)
            {
                var savePath = "monitor" + i+".jpg";
                var x = screen.Bounds.Location.X;
                var y = screen.Bounds.Location.Y;
                var w = screen.Bounds.Width;
                var h = screen.Bounds.Height;
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Monitor: " + i + " extents:" + x + "," + y + " " + w + "," + h);
                using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(w, h))
                {
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                    {
                        g.CopyFromScreen(x, y, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
                    }

                    bmp.Save(savePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("saved: " + savePath);
                }
                i++;
            }



        }
    }
}
```

PS: I get different values based on what I set "dpiaware" in the manifest file: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/054c1d49-9f24-4617-aa83-9bc4f1bb4a5d/use-appmanifest-file-to-make-winforms-application-dpi-aware?forum=vbgeneral

If I don't set dpiaware, then the primary monitor's bounds get halved (cropping out 3/4ths of the screen).
If I set dpiaware to true, then the secondary monitor's bounds get doubled (leaving big black areas in the screenshot).

Comment: If run your code in console application (on .NET 4.7) I get expected results (correct screenshots of both monitors).

Comment: Thanks @Evk, Which monitor on your setup has scaled DPI? The primary or the secondary? I think it might matter that the primary is the scaled one. If it is the primary that is scaled, are you using a manifest with "<dpiaware>", or just the the defaults?

Comment: I use defaults (not touched manifest), my primary is scaled to 150%, secondary (smaller) is at 100% (note that app is console application, not winforms, if that matters).

Comment: @Evk My app is also a console app. I tried scaling my bigger primary to 150% (instead of 200%), and got the same bug. One more question: My primary is on the left (x=0), and my secondary is on the right (x=2880). Is your setup the same?

Comment: @Hans Passant I specified that I tried both manifest "<dpiaware>" options: Getting opposite (but bad) results with both settings. With dpiaware=false, my primary monitor bounds are too small. With dpiaware=true my secondary monitor bounds are too large. I also tried to run the console window on different monitors (that did not have any effect).

Comment: Nobody can tell from the question which "both" out of the 3 possible values you tried.  Not True/PM probably.

Comment: @Hans Passant I am afraid I've lost you. I've tried true and false. (I've also tried not specifying a manifest, which I assume is an implicit false). What is the 3rd possible value?

Comment: @eshalev true and false are not only possible values for this element: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx. It can also contain "true/pm" or "per monitor".

Comment: Well that was @HansPassant suggestion, not mine. Still interesting why it works "out of the box" for me, maybe .NET 4.7 made this a default behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the solution is to set the app.manifest dpiAware tag to **"true/pm"**. The effect is different than just setting it to true.

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true/pm</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, adding the manifest is the way to go. I tried all the solutions, and ended up adding a app.manifest to my project with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">True/PM</dpiAware>
      <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2, PerMonitor</dpiAwareness>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>

</assembly>
```

Finally no need to import any ddl or what so ever.