# Getting a screenshot from a DPI unaware app (a bug in DPI for GetDC/BitBlt / GetDC(0) ignores DPI settings)

Tags: windows, gdi, dpi

Suppose I have a primary monitor, which starts at 0x0 and have the typical size of 1920x1080. My DPI for primary monitor is set to 125%, which results in DPI being 120.

Now, I want to take a screenshot of my monitor.

I will use the [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291167/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-in-a-windows-application) (error checking is removed for simplicity):

```
DC = GetDC(0);
GetDeviceCaps(DC, LOGPIXELSX);  // returns 120
GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);  // returns 1920
W = GetDeviceCaps(DC, HORZRES); // returns 1920
H = GetDeviceCaps(DC, VERTRES); // returns 1080
Bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(DC, W, H);
BmpDC = CreateCompatibleDC(DC);
SelectObject(BmpDC, Bmp);
BitBlt(BmpDC, 0, 0, W, H, DC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

This code would run fine, if my application is DPI awared (for example, via a manifest). `W` will be 1920, `H` will be 1080, and the resulting `Bmp` will hold a screenshot of my monitor.

However, if my application is NOT DPI awared (for example, does not have a manifest), then all Windows functions will report scaled values, which results in:

```
LOGPIXELSX = 96;
SM_CXSCREEN = 1536;
HORZRES = 1536;
VERTRES = 864;
```

So far so good.

However, the code above will produce a clipped result: while the resulting image will have size of 1536x864, but it will contain only partial copy of the desktop (e.g. pixels are one-to-one, without scaling).

There is a clear difference in what functions returns for `GetDC(0)` (e.g. DPI is 96, width is 1536) vs what this DC is actually represents (DPI is 120, width is 1920). In other words, the bitmap associated with the `GetDC(0)` is NOT scaled for the virtualized DPI. This behaviour looks clearly wrong to me.

Question 1: Is this a bug?

Question 2: How to make a screenshot of the monitor, which will work in non-DPI awared app?

P.S. Making application DPI awared is not a solution to the question.

P.P.S. I am using Windows 10.0.19044.1889.

P.P.P.S. I also tried to [detect if application was scaled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507031/detect-if-non-dpi-aware-application-has-been-scaled-virtualized), but `GetDPIForMonitor` returns 96, `GetScaleFactorForMonitor` returns 100, `GetMonitorInfo` returns 1536x864. In other words, I can not find how to detect the real 1920x1080 size of the desktop for using with `BitBlt`.

P.P.P.P.S. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47015893/windows-screenshot-with-scaling), but the "solution" is to "make process DPI awared", which is not what I am asking.

Comment: Why is being DPI aware not a solution?

Comment: @Anders Because it is not my application.

Comment: But are you inside the process? Can you make a new thread in the process?

Comment: @Anders I do not understand what you are asking. I have provided the code that I run in non-DPI aware app - and the unexpected results that this code produces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems [LogicalToPhysicalPointForPerMonitorDPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-logicaltophysicalpointforpermonitordpi) will do the conversion you need.

```cpp
#define NOMINMAX
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto hdc = ::GetDC(NULL);
    const auto dpi = ::GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX);
    const auto cx = ::GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZRES);
    const auto cy = ::GetDeviceCaps(hdc, VERTRES);
    auto corner = POINT{cx, cy};
    ::LogicalToPhysicalPointForPerMonitorDPI(NULL, &corner);
    ::ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    std::cout << "DPI:              " << dpi << '\n'
              << "logical size:     " << cx << " x " << cy << '\n'
              << "physical size:    " << corner.x << " x " << corner.y
              << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

On my machine I get:

```
DPI:              96
logical size:     2194 x 1234
physical size:    3840 x 2160
```